# Beginner Coding - Repeating a Rock, Paper, Scissors game using a while loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

I'm a bare basic coder who is just starting out and I have this assignment where at the end of the game, it asks the user if they want to play again, and they input Y or N.  My problem is when they hit Y to play again, my def game( ) prints out the results of the first match from the last game instead of repeating the whole game.  The rest of my code runs fine.
Here is my code so far:

```
`def intro():
    print "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors."
    print "This is a game between two opponents!"
    print "Have Fun!"
    print
def rematch():
    while 1:
        retry = raw_input("Would you like to play again? Y or N: ")
        if retry == 'Y':
            game() 
        else:
            ending()
            break
def ending():
    print "Thank you for playing!"
    print "Please come back and try again."
def game():
    if player1 == "p" and player2 == "r":
        print
        print "Player 1 wins"
        return 1
    elif player1 == "s" and player2 == "p":
        print
        print "Player 1 wins"
        return 1
    elif player1 == "r" and player2 == "s":
        print
        print "Player 1 wins"
        return 1
    elif player1 == "p" and player2 == "s":
        print
        print "Player 2 wins"
        return 2
    elif player1 == "s" and player2 == "r":
        print
        print "Player 2 wins"
        return 2
    elif player1 == "r" and player2 == "p":
        print
        print "Player 2 wins"
        return 2
    elif player1 == "p" and player2 == "p":
        print
        print "Tie"
        return 0
    elif player1 == "s" and player2 == "s":
        print
        print "Tie"
        return 0
    elif player1 == "r" and player2 == "r":
        print
        print "Tie"
        return 0
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
intro()
player1 = raw_input("Player 1 what is your choice, (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? ").lower()
player2 = raw_input("Player 2 what is your choice, (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? ").lower()
game1 = game()
if game1 == 1:
    score1 = score1 + 1
    print
    print "Player 1's score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's score is ", score2
elif game1 == 2:
    score2 = score2 + 1
    print
    print "Player 1's score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's score is ", score2
elif game1 == 0:
    print
    print "Player 1's score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's score is ", score2
    print
    print "Get ready for Round 2!"
    print
player3 = raw_input("Player 1 what is your choice, (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? ").lower()
player4 = raw_input("Player 2 what is your choice, (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? ").lower()
game2 = game()
if game2 == 1:
    score1 = score1 + 1
    print
    print "Player 1's score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's score is ", score2
elif game2 == 2:
    score2 = score2 + 1
    print
    print "Player 1's score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's score is ", score2
elif game2 == 0:
    print
    print "Player 1's score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's score is ", score2
    print
    print "Final Round!"
    print
player5 = raw_input("Player 1 what is your choice, (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? ").lower()
player6 = raw_input("Player 2 what is your choice, (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? ").lower()
game3 = game()
if game2 == 1:
    score1 = score1 + 1
    print
    print "Player 1's final score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's final score is ", score2
elif game2 == 2:
    score2 = score2 + 1
    print
    print "Player 1's final score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's final score is ", score2
elif game2 == 0:
    print
    print "Player 1's final score is ", score1
    print "Player 2's final score is ", score2 
rematch()`
```

It's at this point here:

```
`def rematch():
    while 1:
        retry = raw_input("Would you like to play again? Y or N: ")
        if retry == 'Y':
            game() 
        else:
            ending()
            break`
```

Where, in my mind, I think game( ) will start a fresh new game, but like I mentioned it just prints the result from the previous game.

Any help would be great, as this is my first time coding as well as first time on this site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simplified example will be more helpful than focusing on the specifics of your current program:

```
def main():
    intro()
    while True:
        play_game()
        if not rematch():
            break
    ending()

def intro():
    print '\nWelcome!\n'

def ending():
    print '\nGood night!\n'

def play_game():
    p1 = int(raw_input('> ') or 0)
    p2 = int(raw_input('> ') or 0)
    winner = evaluate(p1, p2)
    print_result(winner)

def evaluate(p1, p2):
    if   p1 > p2: return 1
    elif p1 < p2: return 2
    else:         return 3

def print_result(p):
    print '\nWinner: player {}\n'.format(p)

def rematch():
    return raw_input('Continue? ').lower().startswith('y')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A few points worth noting:

- All code resides inside of functions. Nothing executes at the top level, other than the last two lines.
- The `main()` function just orchestrates things and does not concern itself with details. The key is to figure out how to express your game at the high level within that `main()` function. In the example at hand, we keep playing until a rematch is not wanted.
- Printing of output is separated from code logic. Notice, for example, that the `evaluate()` function takes data and returns data: it does not print. If we were carrying this principle all the way, we would also move the other user interactions (calls to `raw_input()`) into separate functions, and we might even be able to generalize some of that functionality to reduce the amount of duplicative code (your current program has a lot of that).